# Изменение общей цены при выборе select onchange

Tags: javascript

Имеется оборудование. У него 5 видов. В каждом виде по 10-15 разных размеров оборудования. У каждого размера своя цена.

Как это реализовать посредством *js*?

На [этом сайте](http://bakery.foodmash.kz/) 7 блок оборудования (исходный код можете посмотреть)

Почему-то 5 вид (противни для хотдогов) вообще никак не меняет.

Как бы он меняет цену для определенного блока, но если закрыть все блоки и оставить только 7 блок, то цена не меняется.

Вот код для изменения цены в опред. блоке

```js
function _GetPriceAll() {
  var _prices_all = 0;
  var _counts_all = 0;



  $.each($(".p-project-items fieldset"), function() {
    var _obj = this;
    if ($(".p-project-list .choise .pactive", this).size() > 0) {
      var _prices = 0;
      var _counts = 0;


      $.each($(".p-project-list .choise .pactive", this), function() {
        var _g_parent = $(this).parents(".p-project-item");
        if (!$(_g_parent).find(".p-project-item-add:visible").size()) {
          var _count = parseInt($(this).find(".b-item-count").val());

          var _price = parseFloat($(this).find(".value-title").attr("title"));
          _prices += _count * _price;
          _counts += _count;
        }
      });
      _prices_all += _prices;
      _counts_all += _counts;
      $(".p-project-items-sum", _obj).html('<b>' + _counts + '</b> наименований на сумму <b>' + formatNumber(parseInt(_prices)) + ' тг.</b>');
    }
  });

  $(".goods-total-all strong").html(formatNumber(parseInt(_prices_all)) + " тг.");
  $(".goods-total-all span i").html("(" + _counts_all + " наименований)");

}
```

```html
<li class="pactive">
  <h3>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="itemcard[]" id="item_211356" value="211356" checked="checked">
<!--
                  <input type="checkbox" name="item_211356" id="item_211356" value="1"/>
-->
 <img src="../../bakery/upload/oboryd/prot_6.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" class="image"><br>
 <b class="fn">Противни штампованные <br>Размер: 
                <select id="my_prot1"  name="my_prot">
                       <option value="4100"> 400*600</option> 
                       <option value="5500"> 400*800</option> 
                        <option value="4700"> 325*530</option> 
                    
                  
                       <option value="5500"> 490*740</option> 
                        <option value="6700"> 500*700</option> 
                       <option value="5500"> 530*650</option> 
                        <option value="6700"> 550*700</option> 
                         <option value="8500"> 550*900</option> 
                         <option value="6700"> 590*800</option> 
                          <option value="8000"> 600*900</option> 
                           <option value="12300"> 740*980</option> 
                            <option value="12700"> 750*1040</option> 
                             <option value="13100"> 780*1000</option> 
                              <option value="13100"> 800*1000</option> 
                            
                 </select></b>
               </h3>
  <p class="p-project-item-desc description">

    <!-- 600 кг/ч, вибрац.типа, с магнитн. улавливателем, 0,55 кВт, 680х820х980, 380 В -->
  </p>
  <div class="p-project-item-buy">
    <abbr class="value-title" id="prot_total_6t" title="4100">4 100<abbr class="currency" title="RUB">тг.</abbr></abbr>
    <label class="counter">
      <u class="input"><u><u><input type="text" value="1" name="count_211356" id="count_211356" data="598.html" class="b-item-count"></u></u>
      </u>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </label>
    <span class="p-project-item-totalprice" id="prot_total_6t2" title="4100">4 100</span>

  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("my_prot1").addEventListener("change", function() {
      document.getElementById('prot_total_6t').innerHTML = this.value + "тг.";
      document.getElementById('prot_total_6t2').innerHTML = this.value + "тг.";
    });
  </script>
</li>
```

Comment: помогитееее плиз